# What is the general solution of a differential equation with only one root?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So to get the general solution I know there are three cases, if there are 2 real and distinct roots, if there are 2 repeated roots, and 2 complex roots. But I have ran into a undetermined coefficient question that is $y'-y=1$, where the highest degree is only the first derivative. What I have done so far there is pretty much always a second derivative in the question, so I have never ran into this before. From $r-1=0$ I got that there is only one root which is 1, but since this goes into none of the three cases I'm used to I'm not sure what happens now. What would the general solution look like when there is only one root? My only guess has been $y=c_1e^{x}$

Comment: You miss the particular solution $y=-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a linear ODE with constant coefficients, a root $r$ of the characteristic polynomial with multiplicity $k$ contributes homogeneous solutions $e^{rt},t e^{rt},\dots,t^{k-1}e^{rt}$ (a total of $k$ of them). When the coefficients are real and $r=a+bi$ is complex, $\overline{r}$ is also a root. Accordingly, to get real solutions, we combine the two together, obtaining $e^{at} \cos(bt),e^{at} \sin(bt),t e^{at} \cos(bt),t e^{at} \sin(bt),\dots,t^{k-1} e^{at} \cos(bt),t^{k-1} e^{at} \sin(bt)$ (a total of $2k$ solutions).

In your case, $1$ is a root with multiplicity $1$ so the homogeneous solution is $C e^t$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the differential equation as $(y+1)^{\prime}=y+1$. The solution to this differential equation is $y+1=Ce^x$, or $y=Ce^x-1$.